# Let $G(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$. Prove that $G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n$.

Tags: generating-functions, cauchy-product

Let $G(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$. Prove that $$G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n.$$
The solution given uses the Cauchy Product. It is shown below:
$$\begin{aligned}
G(x)&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n.
\end{aligned}$$
My question is that I don't understand why the equations after the second equal symbol are reached. What I know is that the Cauchy Product is used here, but how it comes to these equations?

Comment: Note that this is easier shown by differantiation as $\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)x^n = \sum_{n\geq 0}n x^{n-1} = (\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{n})' = \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)'=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cauchy product for general series is:
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}
$$
In you case, $a_n=b_n=x^n$ for all $n$, so $a_kb_{n-k}=x^kx^{n-k}=x^n$. Making that replacement explains the second equality. The third equality follows since you $\sum_{k=0}^nx^n$ is the sum of $n+1$ copies of $x^n$, and therefore equal to $(n+1)x^n$.

Comment: One more question. Is it necessary that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent if I want to use this formula?

Comment: The product of the series is only guaranteed to be convergent if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are both convergent, _and_ if at least one of them is absolutely convergent.

Comment: So to make things clearer, the formula is always applicable, but the resulting series is convergent whenever $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent or one of them is absolutely convergent?

Comment: @R.C Yes, that's correct